# Is there any software which could display webpages using custom URLs and it could be work on top of other applications?

Tags: web-browser, windows-10, chromium, electron

I'm currently grappling with a challenge outlined in the title and would appreciate your recommendations.

To provide some context, I've developed a hobby project related to Formula 1, which serves as a system for displaying webpage content. Specifically, it showcases updates from my virtual F1 league and FIA decisions on-screen, akin to real-life broadcasts. I manage the content backend, ensuring webpage refreshes upon sending new information. Additionally, I integrate this content into Twitch streams via OBS's web display feature, with supplementary custom messages sent to Discord, albeit their relevance is secondary.

My next endeavor involves finding or developing a Windows application for the league's racing drivers to use on their personal screens. This application would provide notifications for events like 5-second penalties or race red flags on top of the F1 23 game, such as like the SimHub does. But SimHub doesn't have any features I'm looking for in this situation.
Furthermore, I'm open to coding solutions if necessary, as challenges like this don't scare me. And I would go with Electron or WPF.
However, if there are existing solutions available, I'd greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure how to title question is related to the 3rd paragraph. Could you be more detailed?